specialization of public type template without specializing class template
#include "vector"

template <unsigned int order>
struct ReturnType;

template <>
struct ReturnType<0>
{
    using type = double; // Return type for value
};

template <>
struct ReturnType<1>
{
    using type = std::vector<double>; // Return type for deriv
};


template <unsigned int dim>
class Function
{
    void value(typename ReturnType<0>::type &value) {}; 
    void deriv(typename ReturnType<1>::type &deriv) {}; 
};


int main() {
    Function<1> interp;
    return 0;
}

I want to write a Function class and the arguments of the member functions are specializations of a ReturnType<order> struct. The idea is that when I implement multiple derived classes, I only have to change the return types at one place in the code. However I prefer to place the ReturnType<order> struct as public type in the Function class to enhance encapsulation.
Conceptually:
#include <vector>

template <unsigned int dim>
class Function
{
public:
    template <unsigned int order>
    struct ReturnType; 

    using ValueReturnType = typename ReturnType<0>::type;
    using DerivReturnType = typename ReturnType<1>::type;

    void value(ValueReturnType &value) {}; 
    void deriv(DerivReturnType &deriv) {}; 
};

template <>
template <>
struct Function<1>::ReturnType<0>
{
    using type = double;
};

template <>
template <>
struct Function<1>::ReturnType<1>
{
    using type = std::vector<double>;
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}

This solution requires full template specialization as specializations without the class template are not allowed (correct me if I am wrong).
Is there a solution without full template specialization and keeping the ReturnTypestruct in the Function class?

Not sure of the usefulness of ReturnType. If it is only in one class, why the indirection struct Function<1>::ReturnType<0> {     using type = double; }; /*..*/ using ValueReturnType = typename ReturnType<0>::type; and not directly using ValueReturnType = double;.

If it is shared, then, it doesn't have to be inside the class, you might possibly add using MyReturnType = ReturnType; using ValueReturnType = typename MyReturnType<0>::type;.

I don't think you can, because in order to name the nested type you must instantiate the nesting type, which you can't because it depends on the nested one.
What you can do is move one or both types into a separate namespace. Usually one uses namespace detail for this with the implied meaning that outside users are not supposed to access anything from detail::.
